# Unable to push view from table view

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I have a table view controller as my initial screen and am trying to set it up so that when I click on a row, it jumps to a normal view controller. Here is the code for the part where I select the row:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"did select row");

    MyViewController * myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
}
```

The NSLog query shows up in console, but the view doesn't get pushed into display. I've also tried allocating MyViewController from UIStoryboard, but end up with the same results. Any ideas what the issue might be? Thanks!

**EDIT:** I have included a screenshot of my storyboard:

[image: screenshot of storyboard]

Comment: Just an aside - your variable names could use some work - "myview" really does suggest a UIView and not a UIViewController

Comment: Are you sure you actually have you tableview inside of a UINavigationController?

Comment: @KristianGlass ah my bad i will fix this.

Comment: @Mattieu I have a tableview inside of a Table View Controller which I have checked to be the initial view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use storyboard, but don't you need to add a UINavigationController, and push the UITableViewController on it? That's how it should work, but maybe storyboard takes care of that for you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to change it to `initWithNibName:@"myViewController"`

If that doesnt work you have to check whether myViewController has an UIView which is connected to *view.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. I think myViewController has a proper UIView... I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: Hm. Rightclick on that UIView. Is it connected to *view IBOutlet?

Comment: And doesn't happen anything or does the app crash?

Comment: turns out that it isn't connected to anything. should i ctrl drag the UIView to the TableViewController header or myViewController header?

Comment: No right click it and drag "New Reference Outlet" (or sth. similar) to the files owner and then click "view". http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24625278/Bildschirmfoto%202012-01-04%20um%2013.33.05.png

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a line [myView view]; right after you have allocated it.

Also remember to release it after you push it.
[myView release];

Also check the connections in IB to make sure that myView has the view properly connected

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Although now when I click on a table row I get an exception.